# Vue3: Converting HEX color to RGB while rendering

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, email-templates

Since some email clients don't support RGB/RGBA color value, I need to use HEX code in my email template but it seems vue3 convert Hex to RGB while rendering. Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: How you are going to use vue3 in email template?

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis it's an email template builder

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use CSS classes (they keeps the color's format you choose), I think your issue is something that only happens in the browser. E-mail clients should keep colors in hex.

> It seems like the browser always converts colors to rgb when setting style through JS.
> https://forum.vuejs.org/t/stop-vue-js-from-converting-hex-color-values-to-rgb/39857/3

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is not done by Vue but [by the browser](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/stop-vue-js-from-converting-hex-color-values-to-rgb/39857/6) when setting styles in JS - see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/2y9b5qLx/2/) (and Vue does all its rendering by JS)

So if you wanted to grab a rendered HTML from the DOM, it's not going to work. There are two possible solutions:

1. Grab HTML rendered by Vue from the browser as a string and then simply search and replace `rgb()` (with  conversion to hex color)
2. Do not render to browser. Vue has server side renderer used for SSR applications which can render into string directly. Problem is it is [suppose to run inside Node](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#installation)