# React - How to display HEX color instead of RGB in inline style?

Tags: reactjs

I have saved HEX color in useState.

The problem is that the RGB color is displayed in the resulting HTML.

For example: I put the same use state in the DIV and also as the font color in the inline style.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Module = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#bada55");

  return <div style={{ color: `${color}` }}>{color}</div>;
};

export default Module;
```

The result is like this. But why? I only need to display the color in HEX format at all times. How to do it?

```
<div style="color: rgb(186, 218, 85);">#bada55</div>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't understand something. What exactly do you want to have output to the DOM?  As you have it, it would output a div with `#bada55` in a green colored font.

Comment: @selbie I need this result `<div style="color: #bada55">#bada55</div>`

Comment: I'm just working on a signature generator for email clients. I copy the entire generated signature with one button. The problem, for example, is that Outlook does not support RGB colors in the signature. Therefore, I am looking for a solution to display only RGB colors

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a react thing, but a browser behavior
if you took a look at the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

it says:  the computed value will be in rgba(). If it isn't, it will be computed to rgb().

so, it is standard behavior and, if you use hex it will be computed back to rgba.

maybe you can use color name instead hex-color: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: I found similar information. However, I've looked at other sites that contain inline styles and display classic HEX colors. Also, if you test it on classic html, it also shows the color in HEX format. And the last time I looked, the other sites generating signatures for e-mails copy and also show in DOM HEX color, not RGB. So the problem can't be in the browser (just to be sure, I've tested Edge, Chrome and Firefox and the same problem).

Comment: It seems like the browser always converts colors to rgb when setting style through JS

Comment: You can try to go around it with something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699134/13083203